# Edit View DDL Not Keeping grouping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my Edit Action I have this:

```
ViewBag.DropDownList2= new SelectList(ClassName.lstItems(), "Value", "Text", object.ItemID);
```

This is different from my Create Action, whereas I just have this:

```
ViewBag.DropDownList2= ClassName.lstItems();
```

The reason for that is because I need to keep the value that user originally picked when creating/editing the record.

**ClassName.lstItems()**

```
    public static List<SelectListItem> lstItems()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lstAllItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

        using (var context = new ConnectionString())
        {
            List<Table1> lstTable1Items =
                context.Table1.Where(x => x.deleted == false).ToList();

            var groups =
                lstTable1Items .OrderBy(x => x.Table2.Property1).GroupBy(x => x.Table2.Property1);

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                var slg = new SelectListGroup() {Name = group.Key};
                foreach (Table1 table1Item in group)
                {
                    SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem() {Text = table1Item .PropertyText, Value = table1Item .ID.ToString(), Group = slg};
                    lstAllItems.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        return lstAllItems;
    }
```

Obviously I want a dropdownlist that is grouped.  But in my Edit Action, it is not grouped.  How do I keep my dropdownlist grouped while also having the original value as the selected value on page load?

**Razor**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.itemID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.DropDownList("DropDownList2", null, "Select Item", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.itemID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE**

```
public class TestClass
{
    private ConnectionString context;

    public TestClass()
    {
        context = new ConnectionString();
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetListItems()
    {

        TestClass className = new TestClass();

        // assumes `context` is a field on your class,
        // set in the contructor, after being injected
        return className.context.Table1
            .Where(x => x.deleted == false)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Table2.Property1)
            .Select(x => {
                var group = new SelectListGroup { Name = x.Key };
                return x.Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.PropertyText,
                    Value = i.ID.ToString(),
                    Group = group
                });
            })
            .SelectMany(x => x);    
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly you mean by "grouped" ?

Comment: @KD [`SelectListItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.118).aspx) has a property called `Group`.. where you can group each selectlistitem under a group.. so in a dropdownlist.. you can categorize each selection by the group name

Comment: is\t it possible for you to specify group while filling your selectlist in Edit action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `SelectList` from the list of `SelectListItems`, hence loosing the grouping. The best solution is to use the list of `SelectListItem` and use the `DropDownListFor` helper method.

```
var yourViewModel = new YourViewModel();
ViewBag.DropDownList2 = lstItems();
yourViewModel.SelectedItemId= "b";  // replace with the value you want set selected as
return View(yourViewModel);
```

Now in your view which is strongly typed to `YourViewModel`

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedItemId, ViewBag.DropDownList2 as List<SelectListItem>)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in creating your own `SelectList`. `DropDownListFor` needs only an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Razor can take care of creating the `SelectList` and selecting the appropriate item(s) based on the data in `ModelState`.

In general, you should simply set `ViewBag.DropDownList2` to the return value of your `ClassName.lstItems()` for both cases, and let Razor handle it.

That said, there's some issues with the code you have here. First, and most importantly, you should avoid creating multiple versions of your context, and definitely within static methods. Pretty much without fail, `using` in conjunction with an Entity Framework context, means you're doing something wrong, and you'll eventually get bit for it. Instead, inject your context into classes that need to work with it, either manually, or using a dependency injection container. Your context should have a request-lifetime, i.e. you should use the same context for everything within a single request.

Second, your `lstItems` code could be greatly simplified:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private ConnectionString context;

    public TestClass()
    {
        context = new ConnectionString();
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetListItems()
    {

        TestClass className = new TestClass();

        // assumes `context` is a field on your class,
        // set in the contructor, after being injected
        return className.context.Table1
            .Where(x => x.deleted == false)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Table2.Property1)
            .Select(x => {
                var group = new SelectListGroup { Name = x.Key };
                return x.Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.PropertyText,
                    Value = i.ID.ToString(),
                    Group = group
                });
            })
            .SelectMany(x => x);    
    }
}
```

Comment: So, just put `var context = new ConnectionString();` at the top of the class, and not inside each static method?

Comment: No. Pass it in the constructor.

Comment: sorry, nvmd I got it

Comment: I have edited your answer to show you what I have.  Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Edit your question, not my answer. I can't see your edit until it's approved, and it won't be.